# Blank screen when trying to draw a triangle with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to draw a triangle with HTML and CSS. But I am unable to do it succesfully.

I looked up the most common solution for drawing triangle in CSS.

This the HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="tiangle.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = 'triangle-up'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the CSS code:

```
#triangle-up {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
  }
```

The code should draw a red colored upward-facing triangle, but it displays a blank white page.
Please help.

Comment: I'm able to see the red triangle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kgohamy0/). Could it be that your CSS file isn't properly linked to?

Comment: looks like you have a typo??href="tiangle.css" should it be "triangle.css"?

Comment: Sorry! It's a typo!

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that your CSS links to the misspelled `tiangle.css` but your actual file name is spelled correctly (`triangle.css`)?

Comment: Correct! Its a typo!

Answer (score 0):

```css
#triangle-up {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<div id='triangle-up'></div>
```

Your code is valid. Are you sure you're actually looking at the correct file? Check your console logs. Are they saying any 404 errors (eg you are not linking your stylesheet correctly)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your href. It should say triangle instead of tiangle.

Comment: It should be a comment on the post